# Ubuntu Touch - can't keep cpu frequency set

Tags: ubuntu-touch, cpufreq

I can't seem to set the cpu frequency. I've tried a number of utilities (e.g. cpufreqd / cpufrequtils), as well as just manually editing the cpu frequency using commands like:

```
echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

Doing this works for a short time, but as soon as I do any cpu-intensive work, the file /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq seems to be over written. 
This doesn't happen if I boot into android, and use an app like SetCPU, and then do the same amount of cpu work.

Comment: that second command does nothing

Comment: The second command sets the scaling_max_freq, which for the performance governor, sets the frequency that the cpu will stay fixed at. Running the second command actually changes the value of scaling_max_freq, but it's overwritten if the cpu starts to be used heavily.